# Android compileSdkVersion 23, minSdkVersion 15, targetSdkVersion 23

Tags: java, android

I am learning to make the weather app but Android studio configuration is Android compileSdkVersion 23, minSdkVersion 15, targetSdkVersion: 23. As a result, I am unable to understand where I have to make changes in MainActivity.java to populate fake data. In android studio videos, it says that we have to add this:

```
String[] forecastArray = {
"Today - Sunny - 88/63",
"Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/40",
"Weds - Cloudy - 72/63",
"Thurs- Asteroids - 75/65",
"Fri - Heavy Rain - 65/56",
"Sat - HELP TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 60/51",
"Sun - Sunny - 80/68"
};
List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(
Arrays.asList(forecastArray));
```

I have tried doing this but the build is still unsuccessful.

My MainActivity.java file looks like this:

```
package com.example.cub_admin.sunshine.app;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Where should I make the changes?

Comment: what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Where did you get the code from?

Comment: Well, you have an empty activity. There is nothing to fake. :D I would suggest to write code first to show some data...

Comment: Error Message

List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(
        ^
  symbol:   class List
  location: class MainActivity


symbol:   class ArrayList
  location: class MainActivity



                Arrays.asList(forecastArray));
                ^
  symbol:   variable Arrays
  location: class MainActivity
3 errors

Comment: This ActivityMain.java file is the default one. I need to know where I have to add this Array String so that I get no error.

Comment: Please add a language tag to your question (click the edit button).

Answer (score 0):

In your activity_main.xml, add et set a listview. This is the container of your futur data.

Then, in your Activity, get (inflate) the listview in oncreate method : findViewById(R.id.idOfListViewInXML)

Then, create a simple adapter with parameters your data and set the adapter to your listview.

The adapter is something that tell at your listview how to display your data. You can create custom adapter for complex representation or use default adapters.

Read [this](http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90) for an example

Comment: activity_main. xml looks like this. Can you tell me where I need to make the changes? 

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.cub_admin.sunshine.app.MainActivityFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Comment: I advise you to begin by this : http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html. It show you the base.